# Magento 1 EE 1.13 - 3 errors when adding new products (related to product view page)

Tags: configurable-product, migration, ee-1.13, configurable-swatches

I have three related problems when creating either new or configurable products in Magento. This occurs whether or not I create the products by running a CSV import or do it manually through the admin panel. I suspect (I could be wrong) that they are related and were caused by modifications to the core files made before I joined this project.

Version: EE 1.13

Theme: Default (but many undocumented customizations)

Problem #1: Price won't display at all on the front end product page (but is visible in the admin panel and the category grid).

this is what older looking items (that i did not create) display as.

[image]

this is how they look in the admin panel:

[image]

But, I have no idea how to duplicate this. Simply adding an identical custom option to a new product does nothing as far as displaying price. What's especially irritating is that sometimes I am able to create products that display price this way if I import items through CSV, and sometimes I am not. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to why.

Problem #2: This (happens with both simple and configurable products). Actually this is the least of my worries since it's just a cosmetic issue and probably the easiest to fix but it sure is ugly.

[image]

Problem #3 is the biggest one as it interferes with operation of the site and makes it virtually useless to customers. When I try to add new products to the shopping cart, I get a "The product has required options" error. Lately this has been happening when I create any new product, no matter the method of creation. I have looked at the database tables and has_options/required is already set to zero, so what gives? I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.. other than manually copying pre-existing products and modifying them one at a time, which isn't really a practical solution. Please help!

[image]

Here is the CSV file structure I am working with:

[image]